# Cannot import AnimeJS in Ionic-Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, anime.js

I have installed AnimeJS with the following commands in my Ionic 4 project:

```
npm i animejs --save
npm i @types/animejs --save
```

I then attempted to reference it by using:

```
import * as anime from 'animejs'
```

Doing the above gives me the following error when calling anything from animejs:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object is not a function
>   (near '...animejs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__...')

However, if I import by referencing the `anime.js` within the node_modules directory, everything will work just as expected. I thought by installing `@types/animejs` this would allow me to use just a simple `import * as anime from 'animejs'` without having to directly reference the file within the node_modules directory.

Why can I import using the node_modules folder but not `import * as anime from 'animejs'`

After importing I call it like so:

```
  openModal(modalPage) {
    // Define modal to open
    switch (modalPage) {
      case 'login' : {
        modalPage = LoginPage;
        break;
      }
      case 'register' : {
        modalPage = RegisterPage;
        break;
      }
    }

    // Open modal
    this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: modalPage,
      cssClass: 'intro-modal',
      showBackdrop: true,
      enterAnimation: this.animations.modalEnter
    }).then(modal => {
      // Hide intro buttons
      anime({
        targets: ['.intro-buttons'],
        translateX: '-100%',
        duration: 150,
        easing: 'linear'
      });

      // Animate slide back
      modal.onWillDismiss().then(() => {
        anime({
          targets: ['.intro-buttons'],
          translateX: '0%',
          duration: 150,
          easing: 'linear'
        });
      });

      // Present the modal
      modal.present();
    });
  }
```

Comment: It may be your webpack configuration. The way you are importing seems to be fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cqs4in

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Could you go into more details on that file? I've never touched it before.

Comment: Can you please clarify how exactly you are using `anime` after you import it?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Added that to my question, the `openModal` function is called from ionic on a button press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your import to the following:

```
import anime from 'animejs'
```

This will import the `default` export from `animejs` which is actually a function that take the params/object that you are attempting to pass.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cqs4in) in action showing the import and passing the expected object to `anime()` without the error triggering.

With your existing import `* as anime`, if you log `anime`, you'll see a property `default` of that object that is the actual function you are needing. Also you will see that import is bringing in various other properties/functions including `penner`, `stagger`, and `timeline`. You were simply targeting the wrong property with your previous import.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: What version of `animejs` are you using? What version of `@types/animejs` are you using? Can you try using the same version as the example and seeing if you have the same issue?

Comment: It is working now that I removed `@types/animejs` I am using the latest version of animejs and was using types 2.0.2. TSLint is throwing a `Could not find a declaration file for module 'animejs'. ` warning but I don't think that matters too much since it is working now.